# Curl of cross product $(\underline d \times \underline r)$

Tags: vector-analysis, solution-verification, curl

When finding the curl of a vector cross product such as $$\underline\nabla\times(\underline d\times \underline r)$$, I can use the identity $$\underline\nabla\times(\underline d\times \underline r)=(\underline\nabla\cdot \underline r)\underline d+(\underline r\cdot \underline\nabla)\underline d-(\underline\nabla\cdot \underline d)\underline r-(\underline d\cdot \underline\nabla)\underline r$$If $\underline r = x_1\underline e_1 +x_2\underline e_2+x_3\underline e_3$ (the position vector) and $\underline d$ is a constant vector then the identity becomes:$$\underline\nabla\times(\underline d\times \underline r)=(3)\underline d+(0)\underline d-(0)\underline r-(0)\underline r $$as $\underline\nabla\cdot \underline r = 3 $ and $\underline r\cdot \underline \nabla = 0$ and divergence of $\underline d$ and $\underline d\cdot \underline\nabla$ are zero.

Hence the final result I obtain becomes $\underline\nabla\times(\underline d\times \underline r)=3\underline d$.

However, the answer I was supposed to obtain is $2\underline d$.

Where have I gone wrong?

$Edit: why\:is\: (\underline d\cdot \underline\nabla)\underline r=\underline d\:and\:not\:0?$

Comment: Do you agree with: $\quad \overrightarrow{d} \cdot \nabla \equiv d_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + d_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + d_z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Is that not equal to zero?

Comment: $\overrightarrow{d} \cdot \nabla$ is jut new differential operator, and in your example you are applying it to $r$. See my given answer, I can write that answer in some more details...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I have just looked further on some identities and have found that in general $(\underline a\cdot \underline\nabla)\underline r = \underline a$, but I thought if the nabla is not acting on anything, then it would yield zero as derivative of 0 with respect to x is zero. I would appreciate if you add more detail, or explain why  $(\underline a\cdot \underline\nabla)\underline r = \underline a$

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak perhaps I would be able to see that the dot product will keep the partial derivative and so the brackets will become $a_1dx_1\underline e_1 +a_2dx_2\underline e_2+a_3dx_3\underline e_3$ but the brackets are not dotted with $\underline r$, so how will the partial derivatives act on every term of the $\underline r$ to produce 1 and hence simply return $\underline a$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla \times (\overrightarrow{d} \times \overrightarrow{r}) = \nabla \times ((d_y z - d_z y)\overrightarrow{i} + (d_z x - d_x z)\overrightarrow{j} + (d_x y - d_y x)\overrightarrow{k}) = (d_x + d_x)\overrightarrow{i} + (d_y + d_y)\overrightarrow{j} + (d_z + d_z)\overrightarrow{k} = 2\overrightarrow{d}.$

**A new comment from February 16, 2020:**
$$\nabla \times (\overrightarrow{d} \times \overrightarrow{r}) \equiv \nabla \times \begin{array}{|ccc|}
\overrightarrow{i} & \overrightarrow{j} & \overrightarrow{k}\\
d_x & d_y & d_z\\
x & y & z\\
\end{array}=\\\nabla \times ((d_y z - d_z y)\overrightarrow{i} + (d_z x - d_x z)\overrightarrow{j} + (d_x y - d_y x)\overrightarrow{k}) \equiv \begin{array}{|ccc|}
\overrightarrow{i} & \overrightarrow{j} & \overrightarrow{k}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
d_y z - d_z y &d_z x - d_x z & d_x y - d_y x\\
\end{array} = \\ (d_x + d_x)\overrightarrow{i} + (d_y + d_y)\overrightarrow{j} + (d_z + d_z)\overrightarrow{k} = 2\overrightarrow{d}.$$

Comment: I appreciate your explicit answer(hence the upvote), but I wanted to use the identity and hence wanted to know why $(\underline d\cdot \underline\nabla)\underline r=\underline d\:and\:not\:0?$

Comment: Ok, I am glad to read that you appreciate my new comment. Well, as I wrote earlier $\overrightarrow{d} \cdot \nabla $ is just new differential operator, and in your example you are applying it to $\overrightarrow{r}$. Since $\overrightarrow{d} \cdot \nabla \equiv d_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + d_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + d_z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, we will have \\ $(\overrightarrow{d} \cdot \nabla)\overrightarrow{r} = (d_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + d_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + d_z \frac{\partial}{\partial z})(\overrightarrow{r}) = \overrightarrow{d}$.